# Non-EU citizen in Europe

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino, living in Bulgaria. I want to know if I can go visit Greece with my Bulgarian residence permit, and is it visa free? Thank you and I hope I could receive answers for that question.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timtic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=BG&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GR&selDest=Greece&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, except for Passengers with a family member
>   residence card issued by Bulgaria. The card must be issued to family members of a
>     national of Switzerland or an EEA Member State .
>     They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days and must
>     travel with or travel to join the national of Switzerland or
>     EEA Member State. **This does not apply to passengers with a
>     different type of residence permit.**

So with a normal residence permit, you need a visa

Answer (score 0):

Because Bulgaria is not yet a full member of the Schengen area, Bulgarian visas do not authorize trips to the Schengen area.  I believe the same is true for Bulgarian residence permits, but I cannot find anything conclusive on the internet.

Your best bet is to ask at the Greek consular office in Sofia.  [Contact details](http://www.mfa.gr/en/greece-bilateral-relations/bulgaria/bulgaria-contact-details-of-greek-missions.html) are available from the Greek Ministry of Foreign Affairs web site; its address is

> 103, Evlogi Georgiev str., 1504 Sofia.

If you do not need a visa, they will tell you.  If you do, they will tell you how to apply.  The website is only available in Bulgarian and Greek, at http://www.mfa.gr/bulgaria; there is also a page specifically about [visas](http://www.mfa.gr/bulgaria/bg/services/visas/).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, for the suggestions and its really help :)